# SQL Ranking based on weighted avg

Tags: sql-server

I have two datasets that I am trying to rank based on their weighted average.   My table 1 has an aggregate sum that I need to compare with table 2 weighted avg, the provide the ranking based on the weighted average that from table 2.  Table 1 is the main table but it needs to get the ranking from table 2 based of the weighted averages provided.  The problem is that the two tables do not have an identifier only the aggregates amounts can be used to find the ranking from table 2 based on the file date from table 1.  Basically, I need to loop via table2 and find weighted avg match from table 1, then assign the ranking provided on table2.  Here is an example of the dataset.

```
**Table 1**

Categories      File date       Weighted Avg 
Brand A        01/31/2014          89.4
Brand A        02/29/2014          50.1
Brand A        03/31/2014          76.5
Brand A        04/30/2014          75.2
Brand A        05/31/2014          49.2
Brand A        06/30/2014          50.2
Brand A        07/31/2014          76.2
Brand A        08/31/2014          90.1
Brand B        01/31/2014          89.2
Brand B        02/29/2014          50.2
Brand B        03/31/2014          49.3
Brand B        04/30/2014          48.1
Brand B        05/31/2014          89.2
Brand B        06/30/2014          77.71
Brand B        07/31/2014          75.1
Brand B        08/31/2014          74.2

**Table 2**

Ranking    Company            Weighted Avg  
1         Company A                89.30
2         Company B                80.49
3         Company C                77.71
4         Company D                76.3
5         Company D                75.3
6         Company D                74.3
7         Company D                73.3
8         Company D                71.3
9         Company D                68.3
10        Company E                50.86
11        Company E                50.76
12        Company F                49.4
13        Company F                49.3
14        Company G                48.3

**End Results** 

Categories   File date          Weighted Avg    Ranking from table 2
Brand A      01/31/2014           89.4              1
Brand A      02/29/2014           50.1             11
Brand A      03/31/2014           76.5              4
Brand A      04/30/2014           75.2              6
Brand A      05/31/2014           49.2             14
Brand A      06/30/2014           50.2             49.4
```

I appreciate any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong this may help you

```
SELECT a.categories , 
       a.FILEdate , 
       a.weightedavg , 
       b.ranking 
FROM   table1 a 
JOIN   table2 b 
ON     a.weightedavg= b.weightedavg
```